# Selenium webdriver does not return correct page when getting roblox group config

Tags: selenium-webdriver, roblox

I made a group ranker bot and here is part of its code

```py
from selenium.webdriver import Edge, EdgeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = Edge(service=Service('/Users/jett/msedgedriver'))
driver.get('https://www.roblox.com/groups/configure?id=32409863#!/members')
driver.add_cookie({'name':'.ROBLOSECURITY','value':'_|WARNING:-DO-NOT-SHARE-THIS.--Sharing-this-will-allow-someone-to-log-in-as-you-and-to-steal-your-ROBUX-and-items.|_you_expecting_it_to_be_here_?_hell_nah'})
driver.add_cookie({'name':'.RBXIDCHECK','value':'_value_of_cookie_'})
driver.add_cookie({'name':'GuestData','value':'_value_of_cookie_'})
driver.add_cookie({'name':'RBXcb','value':'_value_of_cookie_'})
driver.add_cookie({'name':'RBXSource', 'value':'_value_of_cookie_'})
driver.get('https://www.roblox.com/groups/configure?id=32409863#!/members')
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
lst = driver.find_elements(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='button.modal-button.btn-control-md.btn-min-width')
for item in lst:
    if item.text == 'I Agree':
        item.click() # new ToS wizard
while True:
    pass # circumvention
```

It returns the following page: [image]
This is incorrect and I expect this page (taken from browser): [image: expected image]
The cookies I supplied are `.ROBLOSECURITY`, `.RBXIDCHECK`, `GuestData`, `RBXcb` and `RBXSource`. Please let me know what other cookies I need or what other actions I need to do to get the page's contents.